# Could not find store in either the context or props of connect site redux error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create something similar to todo app with react and redux from [here](http://www.react.express/react_redux).I have been reading all the solutions for this problem and nothing seems to be working for my case.

Most of the solutions purpose using Provider which I am already using. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit - Few import statement might be missing in snippets, but all components are being imported whenever needed and actions are also defined in action file.

Index.js

```js
import App from './components/App'
import reducer from './reducers/index'

const store = createStore(reducer)

const AppWithStore = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(AppWithStore, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Update - Combined Reducer code

```js
import React from 'react'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import TestReducer from './TestReducer'

export default combineReducers({
 TestReducer,
})
```

App.js

```js
import Test from './Test';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Test />
    );}
}

ReactDOM.render(
    (<App/>),
    document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App
```

Test.js contains both component and container

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { add } from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: state.todos,
})

class Test extends Component {
  dosomething() {
    const dispatch = this.props;
    dispatch(add("New Note"));
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      < button OnClick = { this.dosomething.bind(this)} > Test </button> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test)
```

The reducer logic for Test is as given below

```js
import React from 'react';

const TestReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    const todos = state;
    const {type, payload} = action;

    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD': {
            return {
                ...state,
                todos:"new todo"
            }
        }
    }
    return state;
}

export default TestReducer
```

Comment: `const store = createStore(reducers)` : reducers is undefined

Comment: (Updated) I am importing the reducers in code, didn't put it in snippets.

Comment: why you are calling ReactDOM.render Api twice and on same element.

Comment: You need to first check spelling difference in 

import reducer from './reducers/index'
const store = createStore(reducers)

it should be 

import reducer from './reducers/index'
const store = createStore(reducer)

Comment: Also if possible provide the error screenshot. That will help us to identify issue quickly.

Comment: @NikhilParmar thanks for pointing put the typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (<App/>),
    document.getElementById("root")
); from App.js file
```

When you call it again in App.js a new component instance independent of others is created, That's why it is not finding store.As store is not passed to it.

You can check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/vy7wwqw570.  As i had remove render api call from app.js it is working now.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to import your reducers so that you

if your file name is TestReducer.js

```
import React from 'react';
export const TestReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  const todos = state;
  const {type, payload} = action;

  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD': {
        return {
            ...state,
            todos:"new todo"
        }
    }
  }
  return state;
 }
```

then import it in this manner

```
import {TestReducer} from './TestReducer.js';
const store = createStore(TestReducer);
```

Comment: Tried this, not working.I also tried with default export with TestReducer still getting same error.

Comment: I have an index.js file which combines all the reducer. Right now its just one reducer, but the idea was to have multiple reducer.I get the syntax idea with (used when no default) and without parentheses (with default export) , but it is not working for me.

Comment: then i hope you did that in this manner
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  exampleState,
});

export default rootReducer;

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing todos: state.todos with todos: state.TestReducer.todos

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { add } from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  //todos: state.todos,
  todos: state.TestReducer.todos
})

class Test extends Component {
  dosomething() {
    const dispatch = this.props;
    dispatch(add("New Note"));
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      < button OnClick = { this.dosomething.bind(this)} > Test </button> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test)
```